# Different prediction of Tensorflow in Python and C-API with SavedModel

Tags: python, c++, c, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I trained and tested a model in python with Keras and save it in SavedModel format.
Then I imported it with the C-API and `TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel()`.
I predict the same set of data in python and C but get different results.
The predictions in python are ok, the predictions in C are not ok, but also not fully nonsense.

Things I have checked:

- Tensorflow Version 2.5 in Python and C
- use of the same model
- use of the same data with same format
- load the SavedModel in Python again
- try different arcitectures
- train without keras in low-level tensorflow

Every time python results are good, C results are different and worse.

Is there something wrong with the SavedModel Format regarding Python and C?

Ore any other tipps to solve this problem?

Comment: The Model was saved as desrcibed here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir)

Comment: Do you have any normalization steps missing in the input data? Is the input data in the same channel order (BGR/RGB or HWC/CHW)?

Comment: I checked this to. Normalization is the same, and channel order is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the dataset was normalized in python as type float64
and in C as type float32.

Same type with same normalization gives the same result.
Thanks @GPhilo for your comment. It was the right direction!

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?  
I have the same issue in segmentation.